# order confirmation email not sent to customer for a downloadable product in magento

Tags: magento, product

When I am creating a downloadabale product and adding a link to it by uploading a file then on clicking "Add To cart" option the order confirmation email with the download link is not being sent to customer.

**Will this email only sent be when payment has been made.**

**When I check this order from the list of orders from backend then it says "the order confirmation email was sent" but the item ordered section displays "video file (0/100)"**

One point to note here is that from the magento admin I have selected the "order status to  enable downloads" as "Pending". Then why isn't email being sent to customer.

Please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do other emails get sent properly from your system? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: Actually I am a newbie in magento and these are my first experience with trying to purchase a  product. Do we have to do something special to enable products to be purchased like integrating paypal etc.

Comment: @Joseph Mastey: any suggestions plz?

Comment: On the order page you can click "Send Email" to resend the last message. Try it and see if there is any difference, if it's still not delivered then there is a problem with sending in general.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Downloadable Product Options
See what the "Order Item Status to enable Downloads" is set to. Should be Pending.